# Shell script sh executable - edit to see script

Tags: shell, sh

Is there a way to see the original code of a executable sh script. (I am very new to Linux and trying to understand what things do and such.)

If you know how I need very clear step by step process so I can just type i the commands and run them.

Thanks for your help. Trying to learn (Windows man for 25 years here)

Comment: `cat the-executable.sh`

Comment: ok I cd to the directory and did cat disk-space.sh.x but it said command not found, but if I just rune disk-space.sh.x it runs just fine

Comment: The command `cat` was not found? What environment are you running this in?

Comment: raspberry Pi is that my issue?

Comment: A shell script is just a text file with the name of the interpreter at the top, e.g. `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/perl` to tell the shell which interpreter to use. You can open it up in the editor of your choice. It is only executable by virtue of having the execute bit set in the Linux file permissions, e.g. `chmod +x name_of_file` to set the execute bit.

Comment: IT looks all funky in notepad++ from what I just found it means the file has been compiled? is there a way to de compile it?

Comment: @AlbertMulder - No, the raspberry Pi shell is generally bash, when you type a command line `cat`, it must be in the shell's `PATH` to be found an executed. On the Pi, if you messed your PATH up, just type `/bin/cat filename` to (concatenate) the file to `stdout` (the terminal) or use `/usr/bin/less filename` to load it in the less pager to allow you to scroll Up/Down (type `q` to quit)

Comment: Also, to find out what type of file the system thinks it is, type `file thefilename` and it will report the type of file. Let us know.

Comment: Running the file command this is what I get back - disk-space.sh.x: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=4066bbd8e5808413659b9e62cadb784fbe8d58be, stripped

Comment: Well, OK, you have your answer, you have a `elf` (executable and linkable format) file (equivalent to a windows `.exe`) It was probably compiled in C/C++ or the like. You can use `ldd` to display the libraries it depends on, etc.. You can decompile (to assembler), but that will not be of any use. As a 25 year windows man, drop by [http://linuxcommand.org/ - Shell - What Now?](http://linuxcommand.org/) introduction. You are going to like the Linux shell `:)`

Comment: running cat ./filename found it and this was the output -  PuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTYPuTTY

Comment: Oh, yes, -- don't do that -- once we have established it was an `elf` file, you don't want to `cat` the output anymore than you want to `type windows.exe`. So I take it you are ssh'ed into your Pi from windows using PuTTY. Your question is somewhat an XY problem. What file is it you are interested in decompiling? Remember Linux is **Open-Source**, if you know where the file comes from, you can just go get the source code `:)`

Comment: Of to learn more Linux and such.  Thanks!

Comment: On the Pi (assuming it is running Rasbain, and using `apt` as the package manager), you can simply do `apt-file search /path/to/filename` to find out which package owns that file -- then you can get whatever info you need about the package. To find the full name of the file, just use `readlink -f filename` and it will return the *absolute filename* (fully qualified path and filename). Good luck.

Comment: You might find `strings`  useful. But your program is not a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

A shell script specifically can be seen in the original text form by simply printing the contents of the file:

```
cat disk-space.sh.x
```

Several caveats:

1. If you mean an *executable* rather than a *script* the situation is different. Scripts are read by an *interpreter* at runtime, which then executes it line by line. Executables may be either scripts or *ELF binaries*. The latter have been transformed from the original source code to a machine readable form which is very much harder to read for humans.
2. The extension of the file (`.sh.x` or `.x`) does not control whether the file contents are executed as a binary or script.
3. If the file really is a script it may have been *obfuscated*, meaning that the source code on your system has deliberately been changed to make the resulting file hard to read.

Comment: Note that the `.x` extension does strongly suggest, though, that the file is the result of a compilation/obfuscation process *applied* to the original plain-text `.sh` file.